# What user is my Windows Bash shell running as when it interacts with Windows file system?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded and installed Bash for Windows.  When I do a simple `ls -al`, I get lots of permission denied errors.

I'm not clear quite how the user permissions are being resolved. Let's say that in the bash shell I set up a user called `moi` and has home drive `/home/moi`. If I then do `ls -al /mnt/c`, I get a bunch of permission denied errors, e.g.

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/c/hiberfil.sys: Permission denied 
ls: cannot access /mnt/c/pagefile.sys: Permission denied 
ls: cannot access /mnt/c/swapfile.sys: Permission denied total 2388

    drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      0 Sep 26 18:09 .
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      0 Jan  1  1970 ..
    drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      0 Oct 22  2015 AutoDiscover
    -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 398156 Jul 26  2012 bootmgr
    -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root      1 Oct 30  2015 BOOTNXT
```

I have checked on the "Windows side" and there is no new user called `moi`.  So, when `ls` reports permission denied for `/mnt/c/swapfile.sys` for example, what user is being denied?

A follow on question would be: what do I need to do to get the Bash user and call it my "normal" windows user to have the same permissions?

Comment: The bash shell will be running as whoever you executed with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows user is the user who started `bash.exe`. You can verify this by creating a file from Linux in the `/mnt/c` directory looking at the owner of the file in Windows.

From the windows command prompt:

```
C:\test>echo %USERNAME%
tim

C:\test>bash.exe
wsluser@computer:/mnt/c/test$ touch foo.txt
wsluser@computer:/mnt/c/test$ exit
exit

C:\test>dir /q C:\test\foo.txt
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is B8BA-E032

 Directory of C:\test

2017-06-26  02:06 PM                 0 tim   foo.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  363,224,875,008 bytes free
```

Notice that `bash.exe` was started by the `tim` user, and the `C:\test\foo.txt` file which was created from WSL is also owned by `tim`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Linux file system using the windows file explorer. It's located in your AppData\Local folder. It's "semi-hidden" but accessible:

C:\Users\[*username*]\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs

Comment: Please avoid creating and/or modifying files under ...\lxss\ using Windows apps and tools: There's a reason this is a hidden & system folder!! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/